# Modifying a decomposition to obtain a singular value decomposition of matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

I've encountered the following question:

Assume that we have
\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1\\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & -1 & 1\\
 1 & 2 & 0 \\
 -2 & 1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Now, label the columns of leftmost matrix as $a_{1}, a_{2}$ and $a_{3}$, the diagonal entries of  the middle matrix by $t_{1}, t_{2}$ and $t_{3}$, and finally the rows of the rightmost matrix by $b_{1}^{T}, b_{2}^{T}$ and $b_{3}^{T}$. The question is:

**Question:** Show how to modify the $a_{i}, b_{i}$ and $t_{i}$'s to yield a singular value decomposition for $A$.

Here, I can write $A$ as sum of rank-1 matrices using $a_{i}, b_{i}$ and $t_{i}$'s (which was  asked in the latter part of this question). But I don't know **what the question mean by modifying** $a_{i}, b_{i}$ and $t_{i}$'s? Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take the following notations:

$$M=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 1\\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}_A
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}}_T
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & -1 & 1\\
 1 & 2 & 0 \\
 -2 & 1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}}_B$$

$A$ has orthogonal (but not normalized) columns.

$B$ has orthogonal (but not normalized) lines.

$T$ is diagonal but one its entries is negative (instead of all positive).

These deficiencies can be compensated by inserting diagonal matrices in the following way:

$$M=A\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 
1/\sqrt{6} & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 1/\sqrt{3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}}_{D_1}
D_2D_2
T
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 
1/\sqrt{6} & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 1/\sqrt{3} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1/\sqrt{30}
\end{pmatrix}}_{D_3}B$$

with $$D_2:=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Setting $$U=AD_1D_2, \ \ \ \Sigma=D_2T, \ \ \ V^T=D_3B,$$ we recover the SVD of $M$:

$$M=U\Sigma V^T$$

Comment: Thanks a lot...